# What Is the Name for a Part of a Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Suppose I have sequences $S_{1} = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ and $S_{2} = (3,4,5,6)$. Clearly $S_{2}$ is a part of $S_{1}$.  What word or phrase in mathematical terminology is synonymous with "part" as I have used it here?  While it is true that $S_{2}$ is a *subsequence* of $S_{1}$, that term is too broad for my purposes, because I do not wish such sequences as $(3,5,6)$ to qualify as "parts" of $S_{1}$.

Comment: A "subsequence of consecutive terms" ? "subsequence of the form $x_{n},x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{n+k}$"?

Comment: Maybe something like "a consecutive subsequence" but, in any case, I would spell out what you intended explicitly.

Comment: It is worth noting the programming usage of these terms, for the string `"0123456789"` you have that `"3456"` is a substring while `"356"` is not.  When it is convenient, one may choose to utilize meanings of words and symbols from outside of mathematics in a mathematical context, such as using `%` as the mod operator so long as you make it clear you are doing so.